# shiny interactive plot outputs the real coordinates on the data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

My app that i built outputs the coordinates of the clicked point but my objective is to output the coordinates of the plotted point and that is by printing out the real correspendent coordinates existing on the x axis .This is the first part of the post i want to resolve, then if it is done then we will deal with the fact that my app deals with an x axis of a date nature then we will plot another plot, instaed of the actual, which in fact based on filtering the data based on that date .But now i want to get  using the code below the abscisse which is written on the x axis and not that numerical delivered but R shiny:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shiny)
df<-data.frame("pr"=c("a","n","z","o"),"value"=c(5,1,13,9))
ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(as,factor(df$pr ), df$value)
  })
  
  output$info <- renderText({
    paste0("x=", input$plot_click$x, "\ny=", input$plot_click$y)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

By the way who can disply the points in form of points and not in form of bars or bold lines like in my example so please do it .i will be thankful.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible:  "Error: need finite 'xlim' values".  Also, I don't understand what you mean by "the real correspendent coordinates existing on the x axis".

Comment: @Limey have edited my post! Sorry  forgot to write as.factor . i mean by the "real" the abscissa and ordinate that are behind that plotted point and selected by me and not that numerical coordinates we can get just by runing the  code  i gave in my post